# Copying images to device in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm having a problem with images in Ionic 3. I've seen solutions that use `gulpfile.js` or `ionic.config.js` to copy them to the build folder, but neither file exists in my project. So far I've added them to `www/images`, but these are not copied over when deploying to device. I've also added them to `src/assets`, but these too are not copied.

How could I get the images to be copied to the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I added an image directly into the `assets` folder, not in `assets/img`, and now it works even when deploying to device.

Answer (score 1):

I also found a solution keeping the image inside of src/assets/imgs.

I wrapped my img tag with an ion-avatar tag and it worked.

in html it looks like:

```
<ion-avatar>
  <img src='assets/imgs/image.png'/>
</ion-avatar>
```